# Issue with my Makefile. No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, mips

I'm trying to build a MIPS program with Make. I have two files that are pretty bare as I want to get the Makefile working before continuing with functionality:

```
 logic.asm
 # contains a main method
 # contains a .globl to print_strings
 # calls print_strings

 printer.asm
 # has a print_strings method that just prints a few strings and returns
```

My Makefile looks like so:

```
RASM = /home/bin/rasm
RLINK = /home/bin/rlink

# Suffixes
.SUFFIXES:    .asm .obj .lst .out

# Obj files
OBJS = logic.obj printer.obj

# ASM -> OBJ
.asm.obj:
        $(RASM) -l $*.asm > $*.lst

# OBJ -> OUT
.obj.out:
        $(RLINK) -m -o $*.out $*.obj > $*.map

 # target
 logic.out:        $(OBJS)
          $(RLINK) -m -o $*.out $*.out $(OBJS) > $*.map
```

When I run make, here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ make
/home/bin/rlink -m -o logic.out logic.out logic.obj printer.obj > logic.map
logic.out: No such file or directory
make: *** [logic.out] Error 1
```

Comment: For those of use unfamiliar with mips, could you explain what command you want the `logic.out` rule to execute?

Comment: @Beta logic.out transforms the .out to a .map

Comment: And the command you want the rule to execute turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line:

```
$(RLINK) -m -o $*.out $*.out $(OBJS) > $*.map
```

There should only be 1 $*.out, like so:

```
$(RLINK) -m -o $*.out $(OBJS) > $*.map
```